# How to update the list elements in a defaultdict(list) dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, defaultdict

I am using Python's collections library to make a dictionary where the keys are integers and the values are lists. I am using the `defaultdict(list)` command. I am trying, but unsuccessfully to edit the elements in these lists which are values.

I thought list comprehension should work for this but I keep getting syntax errors. I attach what I have tried below:

```py
import collections 

test = collections.defaultdict(list) 
test[4].append(1)
test[4].append(5)
test[4].append(6)
#This would yield {4: [1,5,6]}

run_lengths = [1,3,4,6] #dummy data

for i in run_lengths:
    #I would like to add 3 to each element of these lists which are values.
    test[i][j for j in test[i]] += i
```

Comment: What lines are triggering the syntax errors

Comment: I have attached some dummy variables. It is merely a list of integers. I am getting a syntax error on the `test[i][j for j in test[length]] += 3` line.

Comment: `length` is not defined, there is no such variable

Comment: My apologies, I have changed it to `i` such that any variable meaning is removed.

Comment: Your question is still unclear. What would your like the result to be after modifying the dictionary?

Comment: I have made it very clear in the comment of my for loop, please check it carefully again. I would like to update the elements in lists which are values of a dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to modify the list in place, you need to overwrite each element as integers are immutable:

```
test[4][:] = [e+3 for e in test[4]]
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(list, {4: [4, 8, 9]})
```

If you don't care about generating a new object (i.e. you did not link a variable name to `test[4]` you can just use:

```
test[4] = [e+3 for e in test[4]]
```

##### what is the difference?

The first case modifies the list in place. If other variables point to the list, the changes will be reflected:

```
x = test[4]
test[4][:] = [e+3 for e in test[4]]
print(x, test)
# [4, 8, 9] defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {4: [4, 8, 9]})
```

In the other case, the list is replaced by a new, independent, one,. All potential bindings are lost:

```
x = test[4]
test[4] = [e+3 for e in test[4]]
print(x, test)
# [1, 5, 6] defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {4: [4, 8, 9]})
```

##### in your loop

Assuming `run_lengths` contains a list of keys to update:

```
for i in run_lengths:
    test[i][:] = [e+3 for e in test[i]]
```

Comment: Is there no way I can achieve this with the current for loop set up that I have?

Comment: @Hamish see update

Comment: Many thanks! Before I accept your answer, may you enligten me on what you meant about 'generating a new object'? This code piece is merely some data analysis for a side project, but I'd be curious to know what the proper way or what nuances are implied by this method.

Comment: I provided an example to see the difference between updating the list and replacing with a new one

Comment: Ah yes I forgot that python property. If variable X and Y point to the same list, and you amend X, then the amendment is also made in Y correct?

Comment: Yes, this is correct